# COUNTIFS, number, wildcard, formula

Tags: excel, regex, formula

I am using this formula.

```
=COUNTIFS(EXCEL_TAB!$A$1:$A$999999", "*"&"#_CELL_VALUE"&"*").
```

How can I specify that that for #_CELL_VALUE, this can be any number followed by _CELL_VALUE? The reason is because the data has the values S_CELL_VALUE (the letter S) and #_CELL_VALUE (# is any number). So I need to differentiate them.

```
Sample Data
RS_CELL_VALUE, 11_CELL_VALUE
RS_CELL_VALUE
11_CELL_VALUE
12_CELL_VALUE
13_CELL_VALUE, RS_CELL_VALUE
```

Attempt code

```
=COUNTA(REGEXMATCH(Data!A1:A999999, "*[0-9]_CELL_VALUE*"))
```

Comment: `COUNTIFS` wildcard handling is not that flexible.   It doesn't support `#`.  You tagged with `regex`. That can be done with a VBA UDF.  Is that an option for you?

Comment: I just realized that. I think I need to go with COUNTA and Regex.

Comment: Yes, how do I use VBA UDF to do this? I was thinking about using COUNTA and Regex

Comment: I am going to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops. Loop Through Range